# PhpWord completely ignores cell style properties

Tags: symfony, phpword

PhpWord ignores the second argument of the the `addCell()` method completely when creating PDF or HTML Documents.  I'm using symfony 3.5 and updated all libraries. PhpWord is currently at 0.14, dompdf at 0.8.2.

I'm trying to output them as PDF or HTML document, but none of them seem to use any of the array arguments.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\ModProduct;
use AppBundle\Entity\ModProductsize;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Language;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Section;
use Symfony ...

public function listAction()
    {
    Settings::setPdfRenderer(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF, $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir() . '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/');

    ....

    $phpWord = new PhpWord();

    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    $header1 = array('size' => 22, 'bold' => true, 'name' => 'Trebuchet MS');
    $header2 = array('size' => 14, 'name' => 'Trebuchet MS');
    $header3 = array('size' => 17, 'name' => 'Trebuchet MS');

    $section->addText('Supplier Name', $header1); // STYLING WORKS

    $table = $section->addTable();

    $row = $table->addRow();

    $w = array(
        Converter::cmToTwip(7.4),
        Converter::cmToTwip(2.8),
        Converter::cmToTwip(2.6),
        Converter::cmToTwip(1.5)
    );

    $fw = 0;
    foreach($w as $value){
        $fw += $value;
    }

    $row->addCell($w[0], ['bgColor' => '999999'])->addText('Produkt');
    $row->addCell($w[1], $header2)->addText('ArtNr');
    $row->addCell($w[2], ['align' => 'center'])->addText('EK-Preis');
    $row->addCell($w[3])->addText('Bestm.');

}
```

Stlying for text works fine, but Cells are completely ignored. Tried bgColor, align, gridSpan, ... neither the PDF nor the HTML file change.

Comment: Whole table border styles also ignored.